# Tensorflow to categorical problem, i want map my masks for segmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a problem with labels for segmentation, the label can have this value: 0, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240. I use this code:

```
mask = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, 241)
```

The code work, but i want map the mask with only 6 classes, is this possible?

```
mask = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

On solution is that first replace your list with ordered indexes and then make it categorical. Because `to_categorical` expects indices for your list.

Here is the example code if you have limited categories:

```
y = [0, 200,210,0,240,230,200,0,210,220,240,0]
replacements = {
    0: 0,
    200: 1,
    210: 2,
    220: 3,
    230: 4,
    240: 5,
}  
y = [replacements.get(x, x) for x in y]
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)
```

Or you can use a simpler way like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y))
```

If you print `y`:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: my vector y is a vector of images, can I use the same method?

Comment: Image data is not a category. If you want to categorize your data, you should have a discrete and limited data to split them into category. However you may update your question and share your vector image and a sample and description to get help better.

Comment: Seems that you are dealing with this problem for a while. Please if my solution does not help you as you expect, share more of your code and your data structure you want to modify to get a better help.